# Is Using Links to Google Maps Forbidden?

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I searched, but I was confused by the terms of use of google, let's see if you can help me.

Using links on my site to show the location of the vehicle on the google map through a link is allowed by Google? Example:
https://www.google.com/maps/dir//-26.236261,-51.092085

And also use the link to see in the street view of google the location of the car, is prohibited? Example:
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=31.33519,-89.28720

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of use (legal issues), not coding.

Comment: You can use links to maps. Google has a [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Reference, see here: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Publicly, you are allowed to use links from Google Maps, as it is a Public Domain and Public Program, and anyone by means necessary is allowed to access, share and even use their code (They have a public API) without permissions needed.

getting access to their API is available using the Get API Key website.
Reference here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

You are also allowed to use any Information/Screenshots/Video from Google Maps if wanted :)